# Botão que some ao rolar a tela

Tags: android, button

Olá galera será que vocês da comunidade poderia me ajudar? Estou querendo fazer o botão do meu aplicativo se esconder quando eu rolo a tela para cima, e aparecer quando rolo para baixo.
Igual ao aplicativo da imagem abaixo, quando a gente rola a tela para cima o  botão some, quando rolamos para baixo ele volta a aparecer.
Infelizmente não tenho ideia de como fazer. Alguém poderia me ajudar ou me indicar algo?

Está dentro de um android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_home" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAd"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/btnad"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_camera_alt_black_24dp"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="@string/btnad"
    android:textColor="@color/background_color" />
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: você usa recyclerview?

Comment: da uma olhada aqui https://guides.codepath.com/android/Floating-Action-Buttons

Comment: Wallace Roberto vou dar uma olhada.

Comment: Anderson, eu já usava o fab, mas retirei porque ele não permite customização nos botões como eu desejava.